# Setting environment variable for VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, environment-variables

I'm installing a software extension for VS2017 which requires me to create a batch file in order to set the 'TargetVisualStudioEdition' environment variable, in my case the variable should be set to Community.
What I did so far is to crate the following simple batch file:

```
set "%TargetVisualStudioEdition%"="Community"
```

Once I run it I receive:

```
set ""="Community"
```

Then, when I run the installer the installation stops because the environment variable has not been set.
Am I missing something?

Comment: set TargetVisualStudioEdition=Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't think you need the %s wrapping the variable;
just do `set VARIABLE = value`
the %% is just to reference the variables.
if this variable will be shared among processes, use `setx`